# Flutter Exception Won't Catch Invalid Image Data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image

I have a synchronous method that reads an image from disk. I'm trying to handle all scenarios where the image didn't get saved properly and is corrupted.

If I place a `fake.jpg` in my app's documents folder and then run the below code on it, it crashes with: `Invalid image data`. So the `Image.file` portion of my code isn't catching an underlying exception.

```dart
Widget getPhotoFile(String path) {
  final file = File(path);

  try {
    if (!file.existsSync()) throw Exception('Photo Not Available');

    final photo = Image.file(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      file,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );

    return photo;

  } catch (error) {
    return Text('No Image');
  }
}
```

Why won't my `catch` block work for the `Image` exception and return the `Text` widget instead?

Comment: I'm having the same issue in all my apps. I cannot catch any exception that is connected to loading images. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I still haven't figured it out, no. 